What is the English translation of this verse
संजय उवाच ||
अनुमण्यथ कौन्तेयो मातुलं मद्रकेश्वरम् | निर्जगं महासैन्यद्‌द्घात्रिभि परिवारतः ||83||
वासुदेवस्तु राधेयमहवे भिजगम वै । तत् एन्मुवच्छेदं पाण्डवार्थे गदाग्रजः ||84||
श्रुतं मे कर्ण भीष्मस्य मालितत्किल न योत्स्यसि । अस्मान्वराय राधेय यावद्भिषमो न हन्यते ||85||
द्वेष तू भीष्मे राधेय पुनर्देष्यसि सुयुगा । धार्तराष्ट्रस्य सहय्या यदि पश्यसि चेतसामम् || 86||
कर्ण उवाच ||
न विप्रियं करिष्यामि धार्तराष्ट्रस्य केशव | त्यक्तप्रणं हि मां विद्धि दुर्योधनहितैसिनम् ||87||

What is the English English translation of this verse


"Sanjaya continued, "Having obtained the permission of his maternal
uncle, the ruler of the Madra, the son of Kunti, surrounded by his
brothers, came out of that vast army. Vasudeva then went to Radha’s
son on the field of battle. And the elder brother of Gada, for the
sake of the Pandavas, then said to Karna,—It has been heard by me, O
Karna, that from hatred of Bhishma you will not fight. Come to our
side, O son of Radha, and (stay with us) as long as Bhishma is not
slain. After Bhishma is slain, O son of Radha, you mayst then again
engage in battle on Duryodhana’s side, if you have no preference for
any of the parties.—  "Karna said, 'I will not do anything that is
disagreeable to Dhritarashtra’s son, O Kesava. Devoted to Duryodhana’s
good, know that I have cast off my life (for him).


Section XLIII, Bhagavad Gita parva, Mahabharata.


Sir this verse I took from bori critical edition Mahabharata did this verse also present in kmg Mahabharat.

@Abhinav Verma - yes.

Sir thank you for your great efforts for me and I have request for you can you give me the this Sanskrit verse with their English translation

Did you took help from chat gpt for the conversion of this sanskrit verse
